# How am I supposed to use SFINAE overload resolution here?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I guess any use of SFINAE could be considered a hack, but here I tried for a long time and the best I could manage was to use a default void* argument in one of the overloads:

```
struct Dog 
{
    Dog() {}
    void makeNull() {}
    
};

// If no .makeNull() function this is eliminated
template <typename T>
constexpr auto HasMakeNullFunction() -> decltype(std::declval<T>().makeNull(), bool())
{
    return true;
}
// And this one is called. But I could only manage to do it with a default void* p = nullptr
template <typename T>
constexpr bool HasMakeNullFunction(void* p = nullptr)
{
    return false;
}

int main()
{

    constexpr bool b = HasMakeNullFunction<Dog>(); // True
    constexpr bool b2 = HasMakeNullFunction<int>(); // False

}
```

What's the way you're supposed to do it? This does work, but the typical way to use SFINAE is with a specialized version that gets called when the substitution fails, right? Also, I don't like the use of the default void* as I could see a potential for a misuse and an implicit conversion to void*.

Comment: What version of C++ would you prefer the answer to target?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts C++17. Or if C++20 has any better solutions, I'd like to see that too.

Comment: I'm hesitant to say this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/257288/1896169 , but that question should have enough information to implement `HasMakeNullFunction`

Comment: *This does work* It really shouldn't. When calling it with `Dog` nothings stops the nullptr version from being valid, so the call is [ambiguous](https://godbolt.org/z/v479hnb3P).

Comment: @super My reasoning for why it works was that it prefers the non default argument version. No arguments are given so the first preference should be the function with no arguments.

Comment: Stating that it works when the code doesn't compile seems unnecessarily unclear, if not outright wrong.

Comment: I just saw from the other comments on the answer that it does actually compile with MSVC. That's clearly non-conformant, but also explains your reasoning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before [C++20 concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints), it was typical to define a `struct` that conditionally derived from either `std::true_type` or `std::false_type` in [`<type_traits>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits):

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <class, class = void>
struct HasMakeNullFunction : std::false_type {};

template <class T>
struct HasMakeNullFunction<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().makeNull())>>
    : std::true_type {};

struct Dog 
{
    Dog() {}
    void makeNull() {}
};

int main()
{
    constexpr bool b = HasMakeNullFunction<Dog>::value; // true
    constexpr bool b2 = HasMakeNullFunction<int>::value; // false

    static_assert(b);
    static_assert(!b2);
}
```

[godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/91nG6jE85)

However, with concepts, it's even easier:

```cpp
template <class T>
concept HasMakeNullFunction = requires (T v) {
    { v.makeNull() };
};

struct Dog 
{
    Dog() {}
    void makeNull() {}
};

int main()
{
    constexpr bool b = HasMakeNullFunction<Dog>; // true
    constexpr bool b2 = HasMakeNullFunction<int>; // false

    static_assert(b);
    static_assert(!b2);
}
```

[godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/nreo6aGsa)

Comment: `struct HasMakeNullFunction<T, decltype(std::declval<T>().makeNull())>` should probably be something like `std::void_t<decltype(...)>`

Comment: @Justin it really doesn't matter. That's just convention, but it's not necessary to make it work.

Comment: Without `std::void_t`, you're requiring that `makeNull()` returns `void`. With `std::void_t`, you're allowing other return types.

Comment: @Justin good catch, I've edited my answer.

Comment: You don't need `std::void_t`, you can say: `decltype(whatever(), void())`

Comment: @VittorioRomeo What is the type of decltype(void())? void() looks like a function signature. The type of decltype(int()) is int because the expression int() returns a value-initialized int. But what does 'void ()' mean?

Comment: @Zebrafish `void()` is a value-initialized `void` :) It may be an [incomplete type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Incomplete_type), but even incomplete types are allowed in [unevaluated expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions#Unevaluated_expressions) such as within `decltype()`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I wonder why void() doesn't parse as a function signature, such as how std::function takes it.

Comment: @Zebrafish probably because the parser is expecting a value expression at that position rather than a type expression, given the comma operator.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Because of the comma operator or because it's inside a decltype( )?

Comment: @Zebrafish: Why do you expect signature for `decltype(void())` but `int` for `decltype(int())` (both have same syntax; I might understand that you expect error for `void()` as incomplete type).

Comment: @Jarod42 I've settled on the understanding that int() is creating a temporary that's value-initialized (zero-initiailized) because int is a primitive/built-in type/no user-defined constructor/however-you-want-to-look-at-it. That's hard to picture with a void type. For example 'int func() { return int(); } Create an int temporary/rvalue and return it. versus 'void func() { return void();} Create a void temporary/rvalue and return it?

Comment: @Zebrafish your example is syntactically valid but ill-formed because `void` is an incomplete type. But that doesn't matter when it's in an unevaluated context like `decltype`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code [doesn't work](https://wandbox.org/permlink/A0JFjFNg1KXiA25t) since when specifying `Dog` as template argument the calling to `HasMakeNullFunction` is ambiguous.

You can define a type trait to separate the two overloads completely. e.g.

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_makeNull : std::false_type {};
template <typename T>
struct has_makeNull<T, decltype(std::declval<T>().makeNull(), void())> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
constexpr auto HasMakeNullFunction() -> std::enable_if_t<has_makeNull<T>::value, bool>
{
    return true;
}
template <typename T>
constexpr auto HasMakeNullFunction() -> std::enable_if_t<!has_makeNull<T>::value, bool>
{
    return false;
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FJnl5b14LAaQIhGv)

Comment: In this case, the `HasMakeNullFunction` is redundant with `has_makeNull`

Comment: @Justin You mean to overload `HasMakeNullFunction` without `has_makeNull`? But how to put constraint that doesn't have `makeNull` on the 2nd overload `HasMakeNullFunction`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that rather than `HasMakeNullFunction<T>()`, the user could just do `has_makeNull<T>::value`

Comment: @Justin I see. I suppose OP wants to constrol overload resolution by SFINAE, `HasMakeNullFunction` could be sample for it, with the help of `has_makeNull`.

Comment: Strange, my code in the question compiles on my Visual Studio compiler.

Comment: @Zebrafish I guess it's VS's issue; especially both [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/A0JFjFNg1KXiA25t) and [gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jrWfMcd0FSQllGzD) say no. :)